# Can't appendChild to parent

Tags: javascript, html

I have `div` where i want to insert rendered content as a child. This  is `<div class="top-news-bar"></div>`. And i have module for that

```
    var fullNewsService = (function () {
    var TEMPLATE_FULL;
    var TOP_NEWS_CONTAINER;


    function init() {
        TEMPLATE_FULL = document.getElementById('template-full-news');
        TOP_NEWS_CONTAINER = document.querySelector('.top-news-bar');
        TOP_NEWS_CONTAINER.addEventListener('click', handleShowClick);
    }



    function handleShowClick(event) {
        var target = event.target;
        if (target.type != 'button')return;
        while (!target.hasAttribute('data-id')) {
            target = target.parentNode;
        }
        var id = target.getAttribute('data-id');
        var templ = renderFullNews(id);
        TOP_NEWS_CONTAINER.appendChild(templ);
    }
    function renderFullNews(id) {
        var article = articlesService.getArticle(id);
        var template = TEMPLATE_FULL;
        template.content.querySelector('.top-image-full').style.backgroundImage = "url(" + article.picture + ")";
        template.content.querySelector('.full-left').innerHTML = article.author;
        var description = template.getElementsByClassName('full-right');


        template.content.querySelector('.title-full').innerHTML = "<h5>" + article.title + "</h5>";
        template.content.querySelector('.content-full').textContent = article.summary;
        return template.content.querySelector('.full-news-wrapper').cloneNode(true);
    }

    return {
        init: init,

    }

}());

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', startApp);


function startApp() {
  fullNewsService.init();

}
```

And when i click on button i get id correctly and template genereated successfully.But nothing happens,no erros and no appending.My html http://pastebin.com/jHxH6zPa

Comment: Can we see your HTML?

Comment: why are you putting the click event on the container instead of the button?

Comment: @RickHitchcock of courese. I think it's the best way to paste it http://pastebin.com/jHxH6zPa

Comment: @Bindrid because i have 3 blocks inside this div. I get click id and insert.

Comment: Yeah. Seems like this line is stopping it: `if (target.type != 'button')return;` Can you remove it?

Comment: @RickHitchcock in ` <div class="top-news-bar"></div>` i have  childs. And every child has button. I get id of the child, and then insert my generated div. This buttons http://imgur.com/a/bXZwq

Comment: @inanc this is a part of my task. But removing doesn't help :(

Comment: @Vladislav then, it's better to put your sample in a jsfiddle for us to see

Comment: @inanc https://jsfiddle.net/dj8czj8u/